# java removing tabs and restoring jpanel back to original

Tags: java, tabs

i have a jpanel (jpanel A) with a button and when pressed 
will open a tab jpanel (example 1)

[image]

so when you press the button you end up with 2 tabs jpanel A and example 1.

the original japanel is now a tabbed panel

when i delete example 1 i am left with jpanel A however this panel is in a tab
.
[image]
is there a way that i can revert back to the original  jpanel when the other jpanel (example 1) is deleted.

[image]

**i have made a sample application similar to mine:**

[image]

after clicking on call a jpanel you get.
[image]

Then click press for tab 2 times you get 2 new tabs
[image]

after removing the 2 tabs you get:
[image]

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO IS END UP WITH THIS:**
[image]
i.e. BACK TO THE ORIGINAL REMOVE THE TAB KEEP THE CONTENT

THE APPLICATION IS SPLIT INTO 3 CLASSES.

1. CreatePanel to make the right hand side jpanel and hold the button to make tab.
2. MainGUI to create the jframe left side to call a panel on the right side.
3. CloseButtonTabbedPane to create the tab and control them.

here is the code:
**MainGUI**

```
               import java.awt.BorderLayout;
               import java.awt.Color;
               import java.awt.Dimension;
               import java.awt.GridLayout;
               import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
               import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
               import javax.swing.JButton;
               import javax.swing.JFrame;
               import javax.swing.JPanel;
               import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
               import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
               import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

      public class MainGUI extends JFrame {

     private JPanel jPanelLeft;
    private JPanel jPanelRight;
    private JButton callPanelBtn;
    private JTabbedPane tab;

        public MainGUI() {

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(1280, 600); // set frame size
    this.setVisible(true); // display frame
    this.setTitle("Tab Example");

    setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // layout manager
    jPanelLeft = new JPanel();
    jPanelLeft.setLayout(null);
    jPanelLeft.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 800));  // to set the size of the left panel
    jPanelLeft.setBackground(Color.blue);
    this.add(jPanelLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);

    callPanelBtn = new JButton("Call a jPanel");
    callPanelBtn.addActionListener(btn);
    callPanelBtn.setBounds(150, 200, 150, 40);
    jPanelLeft.add(callPanelBtn);

    jPanelRight = new JPanel();
    jPanelRight.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    jPanelRight.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    this.add(jPanelRight);

    tab = new CloseButtonTabbedPane();

}//endd constructor

ActionListener btn = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if (ae.getActionCommand() == "Call a jPanel") {
            jPanelRight.add(new CreatePanel(t));
            jPanelRight.revalidate();

        }
    }

};

//    Actionlistener for CreatePanel
ActionListener t = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if (tab.getTabCount() <= 8) {

            // if no tabs make main tab
            if (tab.getTabCount() == 0) {

                tab.addTab("Main Content", jPanelRight); // name for listener not to close
                add(tab);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }

            if (tab.getTabCount() > 0) {
                JPanel newJPanel = new JPanel();
                tab.addTab("new ", newJPanel);

                tab.setSelectedIndex(tab.getTabCount() - 1);
            }
        }

    }

};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            new MainGUI();
        }

    });

} // end main

 }//end class
```

**CreatePanel**

```
                    import java.awt.Color;
                    import java.awt.Dimension;
                    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
                    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
                    import javax.swing.JButton;
                    import javax.swing.JPanel;


                   public class CreatePanel extends JPanel {
                    private JPanel jPanel1;
                    private final JButton tabBTN;

public CreatePanel(ActionListener t){
jPanel1 = new JPanel();
jPanel1.setLayout(null);
jPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(1, Color.lightGray, Color.lightGray));
jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850, 300));
jPanel1.setBackground(Color.green);
add(jPanel1);

 //add button for tabs
    tabBTN = new JButton("Press for Tab");
    tabBTN.setBounds(400, 100, 150, 30);
    tabBTN.addActionListener(t);
    jPanel1.add(tabBTN);
    }//end constructor
   }//end class
```

**CloseButtonTabbedPane**

```
                      import javax.swing.*;
                      import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalIconFactory;
                      import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTabbedPaneUI;
                      import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
                      import java.awt.*;
                      import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
                      import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
                      import java.io.IOException;
                      import java.util.logging.Level;
                      import java.util.logging.Logger;

                    public class CloseButtonTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane {

public CloseButtonTabbedPane() {

}

@Override
public void addTab(String title, Icon icon, Component component, String tip) {
    super.addTab(title, icon, component, tip);
    int count = this.getTabCount() - 1;
    setTabComponentAt(count, new CloseButtonTab(component, title, icon));
}

@Override
public void addTab(String title, Icon icon, Component component) {
    addTab(title, icon, component, null);
}

@Override
public void addTab(String title, Component component) {
    addTab(title, null, component);
}

public class CloseButtonTab extends JPanel {

    private Component tab;

    public CloseButtonTab(final Component tab, String title, Icon icon) {
        this.tab = tab;
        setOpaque(false);
        FlowLayout flowLayout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 3, 3);
        setLayout(flowLayout);
        setVisible(true);

        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel(title);
        jLabel.setIcon(icon);
        add(jLabel);

        JButton button = new JButton(MetalIconFactory.getInternalFrameCloseIcon(16));
        button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1));
        button.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                JTabbedPane tabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) getParent().getParent();
                if (tabbedPane.getSelectedIndex() >= 1) {
                    tabbedPane.remove(tab);
                }

            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
                button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 1));
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
                button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, 1));
            }
        });

        add(button);

    }
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is factory solution but for all `JComponents` you can set a custom UI Object that handles the Look & Feel means the appearance using the `setUI` method. One implementation for `JTabbedPanes` is called `BasicTabbedPaneUI` and has a method `calculateTabAreaHeight` that should calulate the height of the Tab Bar on Top.
So you could set your own instance of `BasicTabbedPaneUI` to your `JTabbedPane` overriding this method to return `0` if only one tab exists.
Put this in your constructor

```
[...]
tab = new CloseButtonTabbedPane();

tab.setUI(new BasicTabbedPaneUI(){
    @Override
    protected int calculateTabAreaHeight(int tabPlacement, int horizRunCount, int maxTabHeight){
        if (tab.getTabCount() == 1) return 0;
        return super.calculateTabAreaHeight(tabPlacement, horizRunCount, maxTabHeight);
    }
});
```

Comment: **That's brilliant thanks**  it works in my sample app i will integrate this into my application and test it.. thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it was useful!